# Receiving 401 from Tumblr in iOS (TMAPIClient)

Tags: ios, oauth, tumblr, tmapiclient

I am successfully receiving token and token secret in my

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

in form of

```
myappname://tumblr-authorize?oauth_token=5XBVeedsLOWmMxVJIi6WiR59Mso5ZuXUZgjEaEfSqb1lVdYwjL&oauth_verifier=p2BdBfBC0CarCQFs9U9wJw5RkkadoFHutpq2pIeOCHSHAI45MQ#_=_
```

now after I receive this I am trying to get userInfo by calling

```
    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthToken = token;
    [TMAPIClient sharedInstance].OAuthTokenSecret = verifier;
    TMAPIClient *client          = [TMAPIClient sharedInstance];
    JXHTTPOperation *operation = [client userInfoRequest];
    [operation setDidFinishLoadingBlock:^(JXHTTPOperation *op){
        NSError* error = nil;
        id jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:op.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
        if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonData]) {
            NSLog(@"jsonData >>> %@", jsonData);
        } else {
            if(error) {
                NSLog(@"error >>> %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
    }];
    [operation start];
```

but I am receiving following in jsonData

```
jsonData >>> {
    meta =     {
        msg = "Not Authorized";
        status = 401;
    };
    response =     (
    );
}
```

Any idea where am I wrong?